# retrieving data on page that was loaded via jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On my main game page I have this jquery/javascript that loads a character into a specific div:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var charID = 123456;
        $("#characterEditor").load('/character/Viewer.htm', 'test = ' + charID);
    });
```

In the "viewer.htm" I'm trying to get the value of 'test'.  But 'test' is always 'undefined' in the browser console.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('charID from game: ', test);
    });
```

In the browser, I see that it's loading correctly:

> Viewer.htm?test=123456

When I try to access the querystring with something like this:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var testCharID = getParameterByName("test");
console.log('charID from game: ', testCharID);
```

It tries to get the query string from the main game page and not the loaded page(Viewer.htm)

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: you'll have to store the AJAX url yourself in a variable somewhere. It's not stored by the `window` any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**

Save the character Id in main game page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var charID = 123456;
    $("#characterEditor").load('/character/Viewer.htm', 'test = ' + charID);
    localStorage.setItem('charID', charID);
});
```

You could access the character Id in the viewer.htm

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var test = localStorage.getItem('charId');
    console.log('charID from game: ', test);
});
```